# Use an array coming from a "with" statement

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have `ids` I can gather with this request:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT mc.id) as liste_ids
FROM mots_cles mc
WHERE mc.mot ILIKE '%Test%'
```

I'd like to request another table with a column having an intersection with this array:

```
SELECT
  a.titre,
  a.id
FROM articles a
WHERE a.motscles && [THE ARRAY]
```

I tried to write a request with this structure:

```
WITH xxx AS (
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT mc.id) as liste_ids
    FROM mots_cles mc
    WHERE mc.mot ILIKE '%Test%'
)
    SELECT
      a.titre,
      a.id
    FROM articles a
    WHERE a.motscles && xxx.liste_ids::integer[]
```

But as you may have guessed, it doesn't work. How could I write my request, I have the sensation I'm not very far from the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
WITH xxx AS (
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT mc.id) as liste_ids
    FROM mots_cles mc
    WHERE mc.mot ILIKE '%Test%'
)
SELECT a.titre, a.id
FROM articles a JOIN
     xxx
     ON a.motscles && xxx.liste_ids::integer[];
```

Or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.titre, a.id
FROM articles a 
EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM xxx
        WHERE a.motscles && xxx.liste_ids::integer[]
       );
```